# Calculating the work done to pump water

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I would like to know whether my reasoning is ok. The problem is the following:

A horizontal cylindrical tank of radius $r = 4\ m$ and length $L = 10\ m$ is half full of water.  What is the work done in pumping the water to the top of the tank?

**Consider:**  $g = 10\ m\cdot s^{-2}$.

I calculate the center of mass when the water is in the down half, and the center of mass when it is in the upper half, and finally, I calculate the work with $W = mgh$, where I take $h$ as the distance between both centers of mass.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: I would use integral here. Set $x=0$ at the midpoint of tank and integrate force required to pump water.

Comment: well I use integrals to find the centers of mass.

Comment: just use $W=\int_0^5 1000 \pi 4^2g \ dx$

Comment: You are expected to pump all the water up to the level of the top of the tank (so it can flow out an outlet), not the CM of the top half of the tank.  Using the CM of the lower half is fine as long as you know where it is.  It is not halfway from the middle to the bottom because more water is in the top half of the filled volume than the bottom half.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clarify the question, I understand now

Comment: @RossMillikan so can I calculate the distance from the top of the tank to the CM of the lower half? Or I have to do it another way?

Comment: Yes, that is what you have to do.  You will need to integrate over the lower semicircle to find its CM